# Split files in to subfolders by song duration

Tags: shell, powershell, foreach, directory, subdirectory

I am completely new to PowerShell and I have not found anything about this by searching around for it. So I will ask here to see if anyone knows if this is possible and how to do it...

I have 1000 mp3 files in a folder. And I want to split them in to subfolders, but each subfolder should have a playtime of 1 hour, or at least as close as possible to 1 hour (preferably more than 1h, than less).

So I'd have to look at the mp3 files Length (they are usually 2-4 minutes long). And I want to first get enough mp3 files so that it is 1 hour playtime in total. Then move them in to a sub folder, and name it `List *n*` where *n* is incremented for each subfolder. Like: List 1, List 2, List 3

Is this possible?

Comment: Try searching for powershell mp3 *duration* instead of length, length is more commonly talking about file size. https://superuser.com/questions/704575/get-song-duration-from-an-mp3-file-in-a-script and https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/powershell-get-mp3mp4-files-metadata-and-how-to-use-it-to-make-you-life-easy/ .

Comment: Thanks, I will look that up

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Please check my answer below. I have managed to get it to work, but there's room for improvement. Could you please take a look at it? How do I get rid of the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Here is the working script! Managed to solve it! :)
Edit the playlist path (the main directory, where all subfolders will be created). Also edit the playlist length!

```
Function Get-MP3Data
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([Psobject])]
    Param
    (
        [String] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $Directory
    )

    Begin
    {
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
    }
    Process
    {

        Foreach($Dir in $Directory)
        {
            $ObjDir = $shell.NameSpace($Dir)
            $Files = gci $Dir| ?{$_.Extension -in '.mp3','.mp4'}

            Foreach($File in $Files)
            {
                $ObjFile = $ObjDir.parsename($File.Name)
                $MetaData = @{}
                $MP3 = ($ObjDir.Items()|?{$_.path -like "*.mp3" -or $_.path -like "*.mp4"})
                $PropertArray = 0,1,2,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,27,28,36,220,223

                Foreach($item in $PropertArray)
                { 
                    If($ObjDir.GetDetailsOf($ObjFile, $item)) #To avoid empty values
                    {
                        $MetaData[$($ObjDir.GetDetailsOf($MP3,$item))] = $ObjDir.GetDetailsOf($ObjFile, $item)
                    }

                }

                New-Object psobject -Property $MetaData |select *, @{n="Directory";e={$Dir}}, @{n="Fullname";e={Join-Path $Dir $File.Name -Resolve}}, @{n="Extension";e={$File.Extension}}
            }
        }
    }
    End
    {
    }
}

# Create playlist
$TotalLength = 0
$MaxLength = 3600
$TempPlaylist = @()
$PlaylistName = 1
$PlaylistPath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New folder"

if ($TotalLength -lt $MaxLength)
{   
    ForEach($item in ($PlaylistPath |Get-Mp3Data)){

        # Get all song names and song durations
        $SongName = $item.Fullname
        $Seconds = [int](([datetime]$item.Length).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds)

        # Append song duration to total length and add song to temporary playlist
        $TotalLength += $Seconds
        $TempPlaylist += ,$SongName

        # Create a folder for the playlist if it doesn't exist
        if (!(test-path $PlaylistPath\$PlaylistName))
        {
            New-item -ItemType Directory -Force -Name $PlaylistName -Path $PlaylistPath
            Write-Host Created new folder $PlaylistName
        }

        # Check if the total length is >= maxlength, then move temporary playlist to a new folder
        if ($TotalLength -ge $MaxLength)
        {   
            # Loop through all songs in the temporary playlist
            For($i=0; $i -lt $TempPlaylist.length; $i++)
            {
                Move-Item -Path $TempPlaylist[$i] -Destination $PlaylistName
                Write-Host Moved file $TempPlaylist[$i] to $PlaylistName
            }

            # Increment playlist folder name
            $PlaylistName++

            # Reset the temporary playlist
            $TempPlaylist = @()

            # Reset the temporary playlist length
            $TotalLength = 0
        }
    }
}
```

To add randomization to it (so that the mp3 files are sorted randomly before inserted to playlists), simply change

```
ForEach($item in ($PlaylistPath | Get-Mp3Data)){
```

to

```
ForEach($item in ($PlaylistPath | Get-Mp3Data) | Sort-Object {Get-Random}){
```